# View bookmarks across multiple files in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

After adding bookmarks in a file, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> can be used to move between bookmarks. However I have multiple bookmarks across many files, so is there a view or plugin that can display a list of bookmarks across all the open files in a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, this is still not possible with any existing plugin or in-built functionality

I found some existing ideas on the [Notepad++ IdeaTorrent](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/bookmarks/latest_ideas/) that cover this functionality. In particular, I suggest going to vote on [#483](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/483/) and [#124](http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/idea/124/).